# Converting pandas datetime to sparse datetime fails

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to convert several columns in a pd.DataFrame from dense to sparse. The following MRE (dense integer to sparse integer) works:

```
>>> dense = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 0, 0, 1]})
>>> dtype = pd.SparseDtype(int, fill_value=0)
>>> sparse = dense.astype(dtype)
>>> print(sparse.dtypes)

A    Sparse[int32, 0]
dtype: object
```

However, extending this logic to sparse datetime data fails:

```
>>> dense = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01', pd.NaT, pd.NaT])})
>>> dtype = pd.SparseDtype('datetime64')
>>> sparse = dense.astype(dtype)
>>> print(sparse.dtypes)
```

An assertion error is returned "assert values.tx is None and aware"

I'm using pandas 1.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with upgrade the `pandas`

```bash
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

then you need to provide a `fill_value` for the SparseDtype because by default, the `fill_value` for the SparseDtype is set to `None`, which is not a valid fill value for `datetime64` data.

```py
import pandas as pd

dense = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01', pd.NaT, pd.NaT])})
dtype = pd.SparseDtype('datetime64[ns]', fill_value=pd.NaT)
sparse = dense.astype(dtype)
print(sparse.dtypes)
```

This works for me!

Comment: This worked after upgrading pandas